# Where put eloquent relationship with Repository Pattern in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I'm trying to learn and implement the Repository Pattern in my app built with Laravel 5.6.

I have implemented my Controller:

```
class CompaniesController extends Controller
{
    protected $company;
    public function __construct(ICompanyRepository $company) {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
    public function index(){
       $companies = $this->company->getAllCompanies();
       return view('companies::index')->with("companies", $companies);
    }
}
```

Then I have implemented the repository interface:

```
interface ICompanyRepository
{
    public function getAllCompanies();
    public function findBy($att, $columns);
    public function getById($id);
    public function with($relations);
}
```

I have implemented My Repository:

```
class CompaniesRepository implements ICompanyRepository
{
    protected $model;
    public function __construct(Companies $model){
        $this->model = $model;
    }


    public function getAllCompanies(){
        return $this->model->all();
    }
    public function findBy($att, $columns)
    {
        return $this->model->where($att, $columns);
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    }


    public function with($relations)
    {
        return $this->model->with($relations);

    }
}
```

And then I have created the model:

```
class Companies extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'settings' => 'array'
    ];
    //my question is here!
    public function members(){
        return $this->hasMany('Companies\Entities\CompaniesMembers');
    }
}
```

For now I have put the relations (in this case members function) in the model, but with this way, If I had to change my ORM, I should change both repository and model, because for now I use Eloquent, but I don't know if in future I will use Doctrine or others.

So my question is:

**Where is the best place the relationships and the functions for db?
Is right put all in the Model or It would be better put all in Repository?**

Comment: i have a controller, entity, eloquentrepo, interface, model and in my eloquentrepo i combine them into a entity to object and in my view i use the entity functions like getName(). This will seperate all

Comment: thank you, could you post a small example of your implementation?

Comment: Yes wait a couple off minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

So in the EloquentRepo you make a function that combines company with companymembers by a foreach and use `modelToObject($model)` Something like this. I hope this will help you the good direction.

EloquentRepo:

```
private function modelToObject($model)
{
    if (is_null($model)) {
        $entity = null;
    } else {
        $entity = new Product(
            $model->{Model::COL_ID},
            $model->{Model::COL_NAME}
        );
    }

    return $entity;
}
```

Entity:

```
class Product{

    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name) {
        $this->setId($id)
             ->setName($name);
    }

    public function setName(string $name): Product{
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but so, you don't use relationship? the function that combine 2 model is a DB::query? or is a relationshipt included in some model?